# Trying to make a class that lets me push and pop values like a stack from an array (in a windows forms application), but I'm getting stuck

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, stack

I have a windows forms application with a numpad on one side for inputting a value into Label1. When the user presses the Enter button, the application should then 'push' the value onto the stack and display the stack in Label2. I'm now stuck at the part where the application stores the value in an array and displays the stack on the screen.

The Enter button has the following code on click:

```
    private void btnEnter_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ArrayStack Stack = new ArrayStack();
            Stack.Push(label1, label2);
            label1.Text = "0";
    }
```

And the ArrayStack class has the following code:

```
    public class ArrayStack
{
    int[] StackArray = new int[10];
    int Top = -1;


    public Label Push(Label Label1, Label Label2)
    {
            StackArray[Top + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
            Top = Top + 1;
            for (int counter = 0; counter == Top + 1; counter++ )
            {
                int num = 10 - counter;
                Label2.Text += "\r\n [" + num + "] " + StackArray[Top];
            }

            return Label2;           
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having here is that it doesn't fill Label2 like I intended, but leaves it empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `Stack<int>` ?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to make `Stack` class member, and not local variable.

Comment: OOP has two significant letters.  You've got the P done but you are not taking care of the first O.  Lots of good books to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int counter = 0; counter == Top + 1; counter++ )
        {
            int num = 10 - counter;
            Label2.Text += "\r\n [" + num + "] " + StackArray[Top];
        }
```

change it to:

```
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= Top; counter++ )
        {
            int num = 10 - counter;
            Label2.Text += "\r\n [" + num + "] " + StackArray[Top];
        }
```

also a new Stack is created every time you hit the button. Try making it a member.

Comment: Do you mean the 'ArrayStack Stack = new ArrayStack();' part? I hadn't realized that would cause problems yet but I see what you mean. How would I fix that? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, thanks!